# Swift Create CSV from UITableView and attach to email

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, csv

I'm just starting out with Swift (and programming in general) and am trying to create a simple orderlist email app for the company I work for.

The basis of my app is from the Envato Tuts+ Swift Shopping List Tutorial.

I know this has been asked a million times, and I have tried and tried, but am at a loss as to how to get my `UITableView` list data into a CSV file and attach it.

Below is my ShoppingListViewController.swift file contents, where I have incorporated a button to launch the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate`.

Could somebody please put me onto the right track?

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import Foundation

class ShoppingListViewController: UITableViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{


var convertMutable: NSMutableString!

func showSendMailErrorAlert()
{
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    self.presentViewController(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?)
{
    controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
@IBAction func sendMailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
    print("Email Tapped")

    convertMutable = NSMutableString();
    for item in shoppingList
    {
        convertMutable.appendFormat("%@\r", item.name, item.quantity)
    }
    print("NSMutableString: \(convertMutable)")

    let data = convertMutable.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    if let d = data {
        print("NSData: \(d)")
    }
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["mh@derivan.com.au"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("From the Orders App")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(String (items), isHTML: false)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "Order.csv")
        return mailComposerVC
    }
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
    {
        self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}


let CellIdentifier = "Cell Identifier"
var items = [Item]() {
    didSet {
        buildShoppingList()
    }
}
var shoppingList = [Item]() {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
        //print (items)
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Order List"
    loadItems()
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ShoppingListViewController.updateShoppingList(_:)), name: "ShoppingListDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
}
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return shoppingList.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let item = shoppingList[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(format: "%.0f", item.quantity)
    print (item.name, item.quantity)
    return cell

}
func updateShoppingList(notification: NSNotification) {
    loadItems()
}
func buildShoppingList() {
    shoppingList = items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
        return item.inShoppingList
    })
}
private func loadItems() {
    if let filePath = pathForItems() where NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {
        if let archivedItems = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(filePath) as? [Item] {
            items = archivedItems
        }
    }
}
private func pathForItems() -> String? {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    if let documents = paths.first, let documentsURL = NSURL(string: documents) {
        return documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("items").path
    }
    return nil
}
}
```

Comment: why have you commented `//mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData` ?

Comment: You've posted a bunch of code but you haven't explain what the problem is. Please update your question and explain what your actual issue is wit the code. And please be specific.

Comment: @Shubhank That was the remnants of a previous test, that did not work very well...

Comment: this would be a better question if you had asked to help in that part, rather then just simply asking how to create csv.

Comment: In reality all I really need is the text contents of the  shoppinglist uitableview to appear in the message body of the email after pressing the button. When I 'print (items)' I end up with hex values in the output eg. [<Shopping_List.Item: 0x13d57ddf0>, <Shopping_List.Item: 0x13d57fac0>, <Shopping_List.Item: 0x13d57fbd0>] instead of the text value. Converting to csv and attaching would be a huge bonus but is really not neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Try The Below Code It may help for generate csv string file

```
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("My app Data")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("my app doc csv", isHTML: false)
        let csvStringData = generateStringForCSV()
        let data = csvStringData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: fileName)
        return mailComposerVC
    }

func generateStringForCSV (currentSessionData:[String:String]) -> NSMutableString {
    let delimiter = ","
    let stringData:NSMutableString  = NSMutableString()
    let currentSessionData = sensorHeader + sensorsData

    for data in currentSessionData {
        stringData.appendString(data.0)
        stringData.appendString(delimiter)
        stringData.appendString(data.1)
        stringData.appendString("\n")
    }
    return stringData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your thoughtful answers, I have managed to sort out a few issues with help from stackoverflow and now have successfully attached a CSV containing my item.name objects from the UITableView using the following code.

```
@IBAction func sendMailButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){
    print("Email Tapped")

    convertMutable = NSMutableString();
    for item in shoppingList
    {
        convertMutable.appendFormat("%@\r", item.name, item.quantity)
    }
    print("NSMutableString: \(convertMutable)")

    let data = convertMutable.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    if let d = data {
        print("NSData: \(d)")
    }
    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController{
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["mh@derivan.com.au"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("From the Orders App")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(String (items), isHTML: false)
        mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "Order.csv")
        return mailComposerVC
    }
```

Im so close it is laughable, but I cannot process a received order without an order quantity.
The question im now stuck with however is, how do I get my item.quantity object into the csv along side its item.name object?

When I print (item.name, item.quantity) I get them together in the Output but adding them together whilst converting to NSData I only get the item.name in my csv.
I've also updated the code in my initial post to the point I am at now.